# exclude a folder in git fetch upstream

Tags: git, github

I want to upstream my fork repo with the **forked-from** repo but, I don't want to fetch a specific folder of their repo because I have my own customized folder in my repo.

except that I want all their other updates.

Actually, I made a **pull request** to their repo and made that folder, my PL has been merged and during the time they updated and changed some options on it. all I want is to use my own customization on that folder, with their updates on other sides.

[my fork repo](https://github.com/Ali-Aref/friendly-snippets) and [their repo](https://github.com/rafamadriz/friendly-snippets) the folder I want to exclude is `snippets/frameworks/django/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way to accomplish this is *not by excluding* their folder updates, but simply *include your local changes*, i.e. in form of a local-only branch. That way, you can benefit from all versioning/change tracking goodness.

A sketch for a rebase-based flow for local-only changes:

1. `git clone https://github.com/rafamadriz/friendly-snippets`
2. `git checkout -b my-changes`
3. *perform your local changes*
4. `git add snippets/frameworks/django`
5. `git commit -m "django: change foo & bar"`

You might even want to push your branch to your forked repo.

If upstream now receives updates you are interested in, simply:

1. `git fetch origin`
2. `git rebase origin/main` (while still on branch `my-changes`)

If no conflicts happened, now your changes are performed against the latest upstream state.

If conflicts are more common, you might be interested in tracking the resolution explicitly, and switch to a merge-based integration flow.